# Making a Trigger Bulk Ready

Tags: apex, trigger, bulkification

I have a trigger that works just fine for single records and I am stumped how to make it work for multiple records.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
trigger TSSEducationUpdate on Education__c (after insert, after update, before delete) {
List<String> TSSEduStatus = new List <String> {};

Set<Id> setContactEdu = new Set<Id>();

if(!Trigger.isDelete){


    for(Education__c thisedu: trigger.new){
        if(thisedu.Student__c !=null)
        {
            setContactEdu.add(thisedu.Student__c);
        }
        //Get Contact Associated with the Education Record
        //????? Does this need to be a "List" or should it just be a single record?
        List<Contact> c=[SELECT Id,Name FROM Contact WHERE Id IN:setContactEdu limit 1000];
        List<Education__c> edu=[Select Id,RecordTypeID, School__r.Name,School__r.RecordTypeID,School_Status__c From Education__c Where Student__c=:c];
        for(Contact con:c){
        //Create string to store Education Status List
        String TSSlist ='';

        for(Education__c e : edu){
            //Check to see if the Education Record is Record Type "The Seattle School"
            if(e.RecordTypeID==TSSRecordTypes.GetRecordTypeId('Education__c','The Seattle School')){
            //Populate list with Status Picklist values
            TSSList += e.School_Status__c +';';

            }
        }
         con.TSS_Education_Status__c=TSSList;
    }
    if(c.size() > 0)
try{
   update c;
}catch(DMLException e){
       system.debug('ERROR UPDATING TSS EDUCATION STATUS:'+e.getDMLMessage(0));
  }
}

} else  {
    //The same a above, but for update, not delete
    for(Education__c thisedu : trigger.old){
        {
        setContactEdu.add(thisedu.Student__c);
        }
        List<Contact> c=[SELECT Id,Name FROM Contact WHERE Id IN:setContactEdu limit 1000]; 
        List<Education__c> edu=[Select id,RecordTypeID, School__r.Name,School__r.RecordTypeID,School_Status__c From Education__c Where Student__c=:c  and id <> :thisedu.id];


    for(Contact con:c){
        String TSSlist ='';

        for(Education__c e : edu){
            if(e.RecordTypeID==TSSRecordTypes.GetRecordTypeId('Education__c','The Seattle School')){
            TSSList += e.School_Status__c +';';

            }
        }
         con.TSS_Education_Status__c=TSSList;
    }
    if(c.size() > 0)
try{
   update c;
}catch(DMLException e){
       system.debug('ERROR UPDATING TSS EDUCATION STATUS:'+e.getDMLMessage(0));
  }
}
}   
    //end trigger
    }
```

Comment: Google trigger bulkification and there is a plethora of info out there.

Comment: What happens when your trigger fires for multiple objects? What problems are you experiencing?

Comment: Mike,Thanks for asking. Here is the error:2013-06-17T15:37:50-07:00,,"",,Insert,,,,," Message: TSSEducationUpdate: System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101 Status code: 13"

Answer (score 4):

```
trigger TSSEducationUpdate on Education__c (after insert, after update, after delete) {
    // Variables for this trigger

    // Stores all status values for the student
    Map<Id, String[]> statusList = new Map<Id, String[]>();

    // Stores all students in the trigger
    Map<Id, Contact> students = new Map<Id, Contact>();

    // Store contacts that didn't update
    Map<Id, String> failedUpdates = new Map<Id, String>();

    // The final list of contacts
    Contact[] studentList;

    // Populate initial data.
    for(Education__c record:Trigger.isDelete?Trigger.old:Trigger.new) {
        // Don't query when you don't need to. Just make in-memory copies.
        students.put(record.Student__c,new Contact(Id=record.Student__c);
        statusList.put(record.Student__c,new String[0]);
    }

    // Ignore Education without Student
    students.remove(null);

    // Find all education records matching the given record type for all students
    // Note that we filter Education__c records that we plan on ignoring to reduce
    // number of rows returned. You should probably use "DeveloperName" instead,
    // though. We also don't query fields we don't use.
    for(Education__c record:
        [SELECT Id, Student__c, School_Status__c 
         FROM   Education__c
         WHERE  Student__c IN :students.keySet() 
            AND RecordType.Name='The Seattle School']) {
        statusList.get(record.Student__c).add(record.School_Status__c);
    }

    // Populate the student status string.
    for(Contact record:students.values()) {
        // String.join can quickly build delimited lists for you. Use it.
        record.TSS_Education_Status__c = String.join(statusList.get(record.id),';');
    }

    // We need to know the order of the records.
    studentList = students.values();

    // Apex Code no longer calls a DML on empty list, so no need to "if *.size() > 0"
    Database.SaveResult[] results = Database.update(studentList, false);

    // Build error messages for students that didn't update
    for(Integer counter = 0; counter < results.size(); counter++) {
        if(!results[counter].isSuccess()) {
            String[] errors = new String[0];
            for(Database.error failReason:results[counter].getErrors()) {
                errors.add(
                    (failReason.getFields().isEmpty()?
                        '':
                        '('+String.join(failReason.getFields(),',')+') ')+
                    failReason.getMessage());
            }
            failedUpdates.put(studentList[counter].Id,'Failed to update student: '+String.join(errors,'; '));
        }
    }

    // Fail Education records conditionally if students failed to update
    for(Education__c record:Trigger.isDelete?Trigger.old:Trigger.new) {
        if(failedUpdates.containsKey(record.Student__c)) {
            record.addError(failedUpdates.get(record.Student__c));
        }
    }
}
```

Several notes here:

- "?:" notation makes the code more compact. I use this notation to reduce the number of lines I need to cover with code coverage. It simply means "if condition ? value when true : value when false", and can be used to great effect when used with care.
- As the comments state, don't query when you don't need to. Also, use filters to reduce the query load (less rows, less script statements, runs faster).
- For bulkification, use maps and sets, as demonstrated in this version. There is always a way to gather data together in a way that allows you to use just one query instead of one per row. It's up to the developer to seek out that way.
- I changed the DML events to after delete. This way, education records won't include their status value for deleted education events.
- You could change the statusList to a `Set<Id>` if you wanted to just know which status values they are using, without duplication.
- Reuse values when possible. I have a feeling that `TSSRecordTypes.GetRecordTypeId` probably doesn't use a caching mechanism, which may be one of the culprits of your query limit problems (but, I could be wrong). The best practice, though, is to simply get the value from your utility function once, place it in a variable, and reuse it as needed.
- When you have to copy and paste code to re-use it, you probably have a design flaw. Look for ways to optimize the code so that it isn't written more than once.
- My re-write shows how to not use try-catch for this simple case. You can use try-catch, just make sure that you're processing all of the errors correctly, and not just debugging them away. It makes it a lot harder to figure out why your code is broken later.